# Ethernet connection does not work on new Fedora install, kernel module nowhere to be found

Tags: fedora, kernel-modules, ethernet, realtek

I recently installed Fedora on a desktop PC and I couldn't get any ethernet connection. Browsing my issue on the internet, I realized that a lot of people encountered the same problem. When looking it up, I found out that the proper kernel module was missing (`r8168` was the right one while `r8169` seemed to be the one in use).

Here's what `ifconfig` returns :

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 63  bytes 6605 (6.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 63  bytes 6605 (6.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here's what `lspci | grep -i Ethernet` returns:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 03)
```

What `lspci -nnvs 03:00.0` returns :

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Onboard Ethernet [1458:e000]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 18, NUMA node 0
    I/O ports at ce00 [size=256]
    Memory at fdfff000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at fdff8000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Expansion ROM at fd600000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

I have tried to use different kernel versions but without success. Tried compiling the `r8168` module but the `make` command returned tons of errors and reminded me that I was kind of a noob at linux.

Comment: Note that `ifconfig` without any options will display only NICs that have been configured/activated; to see unconfigured NICs too, you will need  `ifconfig -a` or the newer `ip link show` (which can be shortened to just `ip l` if you don't want to type it in full).

Comment: Here's the return : `[elton@fedora ~]$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s19f2u5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6a:ab:47:51:91:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
`

Answer (score 1):

Your lspci does say "Kernel modules: r8169", but not "Kernel driver in use: r8169". Which leads to the question whether the kernel module is actually loaded. Check first whether it is loaded with "lsmod | grep r8". If nothing is returned then it's not loaded and you can try to load it with "sudo modprobe r8169" and test again with "lsmod | grep r8".

Good luck.

Comment: Here's the result of lsmod | grep r8 :
`r8169                 102400  0`
So I guess it's loaded ?
Sorry for the delay, I just moved places

Comment: Yep, it's loaded, just not in use. Run the lspci with sudo, to get more info: 'sudo lspci -nnvs 03:00.0'. Debugging you network startup would show more: 'sudo journalctl -b -a -u NetworkManager'. Search for the network driver name (r8169).

Comment: I replied to your comment in an answer (return is too long)

Comment: Is your computer connected to the network? Do you have a LED or such lighting up? Suspecting hardware. If not: connect and test again. To exclude your distribution, I would boot from a live version of another one from usb or cd/dvd, Ubuntu is pretty good at this: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install.

Comment: There is a light showing near the ethernet port when it's plugged in. I'm going to try a live distro as suggested

Comment: So I tried with live ubuntu but it did not work either. I think that you are right about it being a hardware issue. I ended up ordering a usb to ethernet dongle... It's an old pc that we salvaged from my girlfriend job so maybe the ethernet connector is defective.
The motherboard is a Gigabyte ga 890gpa ud3h if that can help. 
I give up.. For now !

Answer (score 0):

Just replying to JdeHaan since the results of the commands would be too long as a comment :
`[elton@fedora ~]$ sudo lspci -nnvs 03:00.0 03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03) Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Onboard Ethernet [1458:e000] Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 18, NUMA node 0 I/O ports at ce00 [size=256] Memory at fdfff000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K] Memory at fdff8000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K] Expansion ROM at fd600000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K] Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3 Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+ Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01 Capabilities: [ac] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked- Capabilities: [cc] Vital Product Data Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 03-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00 Kernel modules: r8169`

I also ran `sudo journalctl -b -a -u NetworkManager | grep '2347'` but it did not show anything..

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/434450)

Comment: @JdeHaan I also commented the output of a previous command here